# "Average" solution to an ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Consider a linear ODE of the following form:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n g_i(t)\phi_i(t) + h_i(t)\phi_i'(t) = y(t)  \sum_{i=1}^n g_i(t) + y'(t)\sum_{i=1}^n h_i(t),
$$
where the unknown function is $y(t)$, $t\geq 0$, $y(0)=1$ and all $g_i$'s, $h_i$'s and $\phi_i$'s are given.

We assume that for all $i$ and $t\geq 0$ we have:

1. $h_i(t)>0$
2. $\phi_i'(t)\leq 0$
3. $0\leq \phi_i(t)\leq 1$.
4. $\phi_i(0)=1$

It's natural to think of the solution $y(t)$ as some kind of an "average" of the $\phi_i$'s so the question one could ask is:

Is it true that $y(t)$ also satisfies 2 and 3, i.e. $y'(t)\leq 0$ and $0\leq y(t)\leq 1$ for all $t\geq 0$ ?

Does there exist a framework/theory within which questions of this sort are posed and answered?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you can make such detailed statements without any assumptions on the $g_j$.

Comment: Also, after uncluttering the equation becomes $A(t)=B(t)y+C(t)y'$, which you can solve "explicitly" (that is, up to integrations).